# Callback when entity returns data

Tags: angularjs, asynccallback

How to call callback when `Device` returns data and pass `this` to the callback method.

**Controller**

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   angular
       .module('frontendApp')
       .controller('DeviceController', DeviceController);

   DeviceController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Device'];

   function DeviceController ($scope, $state, Device) {
       var vm = this;

       vm.devices = [];

       loadAll();

       function updateMap(flag){
       var self = this;//how to pass "this" from loadAll()?
       // logic to update map
       }

       function loadAll() {
           Device.query(function(result) {
               vm.devices = result;
               // Callback function here - updateMap(true)
           });
       }
   }
})();
```

**Service**

```
function Device ($resource, DateUtils) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/devices/:id';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you expect `this` to refer, controller, vm or service?

Comment: `this` to refer controller. I am trying to call other methods defined in the controller from `updateMap`.

Comment: You can use `vm` directly inside the `updateMap`. I don't find any issues. Can you give a try?

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you can use `vm` directly inside the `updateMap` function as below.

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   angular
       .module('frontendApp')
       .controller('DeviceController', DeviceController);

   DeviceController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Device'];

   function DeviceController ($scope, $state, Device) {
       var vm = this;

       vm.devices = [];

       loadAll();

       function updateMap(flag){
         console.log(vm.devices);
       }

       function loadAll() {
           Device.query(function(result) {
               vm.devices = result;
               // Callback function here - updateMap(true)
           });
       }
   }
})();
```